# Kotlin variable inferred type (MutableMap<K,V>)..Map<K, V>). What does it mean?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

IDEA 2021 Quick documentation tooltip shows strange inferred type for Kotlin local variable: `(MutableMap<K,V>)..Map<K, V>)`.

It is the first time I encountered this type definition syntax `(X..Y)`.
What does it mean?

[image: Quick documentation tooltip]

Comment: It might help to see the code this goes with. @AliSh What would a range of Maps be?

Comment: Variable is `Map` returned from Reactor [collectMap() method](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collectMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-).  Actually method return value is inferred as bizarre `Mono<(MutableMap<K,V>)..Map<K, V>)>` and  I transform it later in the reactive pipeline. I try to make concise code sample later but is definitely not a range.

Comment: I was wondering whether it's saying that the return type is a *Java* `Map`, which is equivalent to a Kotlin `MutableMap` (because saying it was just a `Map` type would confuse it with the Kotlin immutable `Map`)? But then again it wouldn't be the notation I would choose for something like that...

Comment: Also it's surely not a range @AliSh, for example a range of integers in Kotlin is constructed with `..` but it's type is `IntRange` not `Int..Int`.

Comment: @HenryTwist The type for mapped Java Map would be `(Mutable)Map`. I’m wondering if they used to have a different syntax for mapped Java Map and this function return type triggers an edge case they missed converting to the modern syntax for it.

Comment: Oh yes of course, you're right @Tenfour04. Very odd, could be from legacy behaviour like you said, feel like we need an actual JB developer to answer this one.

Comment: Yeah. It looks like odd version of `(Mutable)Map`.